# How to get maxPwdAge for by Organization Unit or Group wise in active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory-group

I want to get maxPwdAge value for specific Organization Unit or Group wise.Anybody help me how to do it.

I am able to get domain level maxPwdAge like below, but how can i get Group or OU level maxPwdAge.
Anybody please help me.

```
 long maxPwdAge=0; 
string domain="LDAP://10.10.1.100/OU=Dev,DC=test,DC=com"; 
string adsiUserName="test"; 
string adsiPassword="test"; 
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(domain, adsiUserName, adsiPassword, AuthenticationTypes.Secure); 
DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry); 
string filter = "(maxPwdAge=*)"; //"maxPwdAge=*"; 
mySearcher.Filter = filter; 
SearchResult results = mySearcher.FindOne(); 
if (results != null) 
{ 
Int64 pwdAge = (Int64)results.Properties["maxPwdAge"][0]; 
maxPwdAge = pwdAge / -864000000000; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely that you're filtering by password max age and not adding it to the properties.